# PHP - How to use config file variables in a function's array?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, while-loop

I could not find an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I guess I don't know the proper search words to use. I have a working script but I want to make it more flexible by adding a main, admin editable config file.

I have the following function:

```
    function ip_is_mobile($ip) {
        $pri_addrs = array(                 
            '66.87.0.0-66.87.255.255',  // Sprint mobile
            '174.192.0.0-174.255.255.255'   // Verizon mobile
        );
    
        $long_ip = ip2long($ip);
    
        if($long_ip != -1) {

            foreach($pri_addrs AS $pri_addr) {
                list($start, $end) = explode('-', $pri_addr);

                // IF IS a mobile IP
                if($long_ip >= ip2long($start) && $long_ip <= ip2long($end))
                    return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
```

I would like to replace the hard-coded IP address ranges, in the function, with variables or definitions which will be set in the main config file so that the config file has something similar to the following:

```
// Mobile IP address ranges. Add as many as needed.
$MobileIPs['0']="66.87.0.0-66.87.255.255";
$MobileIPs['1']="174.192.0.0-174.255.255.255";
$MobileIPs['2']="85.110.50.0/24";
```

My goal is to give the admin an easy to read and understand way of adding as many IP address ranges as necessary (probably 20 max). I'm not opposed to totally rewriting the function if there is a better, more efficient way. In addition to IP ranges, it would be advantageous if CIDR's could also be specified; as indicated in the last code line above.

What edits do I need to make to the function and what would the corresponding lines in the main config file be so that the user can add any number of ranges or CIDR's?

Comment: I mean you need some Database for store IP ranges. Admin will be able to add/remove/change ranges by DB, and script will read data from DB and do it's job

Comment: Slava, there won't be enough IP ranges to justify using a DB for them. That's why I want them specified in the config file. These ranges will be used to parse a DB of individual IP addresses which were already logged. Make sense or did I not understand your comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can store configuration of ip ranges in separate configuration file and use `require_once` in your main code

**ip_ranges.conf.php** (configuration file)

```
<?php

    $pri_addrs = array(                 
        '66.87.0.0-66.87.255.255',    // Sprint mobile
        '174.192.0.0-174.255.255.255' // Verizon mobile
    );
```

**index.php** (main code file)

```
function ip_is_mobile($ip) {
    require_once(ip_ranges.conf.php); // include config file

    $long_ip = ip2long($ip);

    if($long_ip != -1) {
        foreach($pri_addrs AS $pri_addr) {
            list($start, $end) = explode('-', $pri_addr);
                 
             // IF IS a mobile IP
             if($long_ip >= ip2long($start) && $long_ip <= ip2long($end))
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Slava, thanks for your example but I am looking for a way to use simple one-liner ranges or CIRDs in the main config file, as I indicated in my OP. I don't trust the user to not leave out the commas (i.e., '66.87.0.0-66.87.255.255',). There must be a way to do what I want with a foreach... I just can't figure it out.